# space between tabs in tabcontrol Dotnetbar VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol, dotnetbar

i am trying to make a new tab and my new tabs always have a space between them

im new to this site so i cant post pictures so heres a link to my issue   http://i43.tinypic.com/rbbndk.png

heres my new tab code

```
 Private Sub NewPageToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NewPageToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim newpage As TabItem = TabControl1.CreateTab("newpage")
    Dim textb As New RichTextBox
    Dim filename As New TextBox
    Dim sw As New StreamWriter(siteloc & filename.Text & ".hsp")
    Dim createb As New Button

    'Set the contents of the page
    textb.ReadOnly = False
    textb.Multiline = True
    textb.Dock() = DockStyle.Top
    textb.Height = 338

    newpage.Text = "NewPage"

    filename.Text = "Untitled"
    filename.Location = New Point(5, 342)
    filename.Width = 220

    createb.Location = New Point(232, 342)
    createb.Text = "Submit page"


    'Add the tab to the page
    newpage.AttachedControl.Controls.Add(filename)
    newpage.AttachedControl.Controls.Add(textb)
    newpage.AttachedControl.Controls.Add(createb)

    TabControl1.Tabs.Add(newpage)

    'select the tab
    TabControl1.SelectedTab = newpage

    'add button handlers
    AddHandler createb.Click, AddressOf createb_Click

End Sub
```

i looked all over for answers and found nothing. i havent changed anything in the propertys and i just installed dotnetbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CreateTab method already adds the newly created tab to Tabs collection (see docs for the method) so you are adding it twice. Remove this code: **TabControl1.Tabs.Add(newpage)**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works! thanks so much, i checked my code over and over and never thought about that. duuuh =D